# Returning to ESO & I haven't played since Jan 2014 looking for advice on upgrading account

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I tried making a post on the official forums, but it requires an invitation, or something I don't understand.

I originally pre-purchased ESO back in 2014 and played it a tiny bit, didn't like it and haven't played since.

Anyway, I downloaded it last night and am looking to give it another try, I am interested in playing the Warden class, which came with Morrowind expansion.

My current license: is THE ELDER SCROLLS® ONLINE PC/MAC DIGITAL IMPERIAL EDITION. I play on PC and this was purchased from Bethesda also I don't use Steam.

I'm looking for advice on how best to upgrade the account etc to play this class. If I do not necessarily need to purchase up to the most current content; I appreciate advice on what to do.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Unrelated with your question and a personal opinion, but maybe you should also give another shot to the original content/classes (the game received some major improvements since the 2014 buggy, crashy, unbalanced version).

Comment: Since I made this post, I have actually been playing ESO in my spare time and really enjoying it. I've been questing in Morrowind but do plan to go back and finish the original story line main quest. I agree with what you've said and am finding the game to be smooth and a pleasure to play.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extra content for Elder Scrolls Online comes in 4 variants:

- Free updates: every player gets these regardless of account type;
- Crown Store Upgrades: smaller convenience or flexibility upgrades available for the premium currency;
- DLC Game Packs: You get these automatically if you're a subscriber, or you can buy them for crowns at the ingame shop;
- Chapters: major story upgrades that you need to buy separately.

Morrowind was originally a Chapter. However, with the release of the next Chapter, Summerset, Morrowind was made no longer available for purchase divided into several smaller components:

- Battlegrounds have become part of the base game;
- The Warden class has turned into a separate Crown Store Upgrade, available for 1500 Crowns;
- Vvardenfell, the new zone, has turned into a DLC Game Pack, which is included with the subscription fee or can be bought from the Crown Store.

So if you want to play the Warden class, all you need to do is buy the Upgrade from the Crown Store for 1500 crowns.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that I can just buy the class separately. It can be overwhelming joining a MMO with lots of content out and you explained how the content in ESO works very well.